# Solve PDE with DiracDelta function

Tags: differential-equations

This question is related to [Analytic solution of dynamic Euler–Bernoulli beam equation with compatibility condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84171/solve-wave-equation-using-dsolve/). I think it is more appropriate to open another question on this topic.

In the question, the compatibility conditions can be introduce into equations using `DiracDelta`. For example, for the spring compatibility condition, the governing equation can be rewritten as

$$EI\cfrac{\partial^4 w}{\partial x^4} + \mu\cfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} + k \delta(x-L/2) w(x,t) = 0$$

Then, we try to use Laplace Transform mentioned by @xzczd,

```
eqn = EI D[y[x, t], {x, 4}] + μ D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] + 
    k DiracDelta[x - L/2] y[x, t] == 0;
ic = {y[x, 0] == Sin[x/L Pi], Derivative[0, 1][y][x, 0] == 0};
bc = {y[0, t] == 0, y[L, t] == 0, Derivative[2, 0][y][0, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[2, 0][y][L, t] == 0};
teqn = With[{l = LaplaceTransform}, 
   l[{eqn, bc}, t, s] /. HoldPattern@l[u_, t, s] :> u] /. Rule @@@ ic
```

This step goes well, the equation is transformed to `s`-domain, but with `DiracDelta` function.

Apply `DSolve` to the equation returns `0`

```
DSolve[teqn, y[x, t], x][[1, 1, -1]]
```

So, I thought maybe use `FourierTransform` to transform $x$ to $\omega$ domain may solve this problem. However, *Mathematica* do not return a result from `FourierTransform`

```
FourierTransform[eqn, x, s]
```

There are several questions related to this question but they are mostly using `NDSolve`. Here are two examples:

[Solving a PDE containing DiracDelta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11162/solving-a-pde-containing-diracdelta)

[How to correctly use DSolve when the force is an impulse (dirac delta) and initial conditions are not zero](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17410/how-to-correctly-use-dsolve-when-the-force-is-an-impulse-dirac-delta-and-initi/17415#17415)

Comment: I don't think using the delta function is practical here. It's probably better to use the general solution in each domain (left and right half) and match them according to the compatibility conditions implied by the delta function. That should reduce the problem to a set of simultaneous (algebraic, not differential) equations for the integration constants in each interval once you know the general solution as derived in my answer to [the linked question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84171/245).

Comment: In v9.0.1, `DSolve` returns unevaluated after a warning. For the `FourierTransform` part: unlike `LaplaceTransform`, currently `FourierTransform` isn't handy. To circumvent this, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871)'s a shell for enhancing. But what's really troublesome is: the ODE isn't defined in a infinite domain, so Fourier transform can't be used directly, theoretically  one can extend the domain in cycles with e.g. `Mod`, but personally I never succeeded in the subsequent step: perhaps a artificial periodic function is too hard for `FourierTransform`, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Jens substituting boundary condition into the general solution and solve the equations analytically in Mathematica is not a easy task to do. Actually, it will be very soon end up to an eigenvalue problem for this problem.

Comment: @xzczd it seems this problem has to fall back to eigenvalue problem. And the best we can get is a not very long eigenvalue equation.

Comment: Is the product of one-dimensional delta distribution by a function of two variables  DiracDelta[x - L/2]*y[x, t] defined at all?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a total answer, but it may get you a little farther with the FourierTransform.  The pde:

```
eqn = EI D[y[x, t], {x, 4}] + μ D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] + 
   k DiracDelta[x - L/2] y[x, t] == 0
```

Although MMa doesn't like taking the ft of the entire pde at once, we can do it term by term.

```
fteq = EI FourierTransform[D[y[x, t], {x, 4}], x, s] + μ FourierTransform[D[y[x, t], {t, 2}], x, s] + 
   k FourierTransform[y[x, t] DiracDelta[x - L/2], x, s] == 0
(*EI*s^4*FourierTransform[y[x, t], x, s] + 
   μ*FourierTransform[Derivative[0, 2][y][x, t], x, s] + 
   (k*E^((I*L*s)/2)*y[L/2, t])/Sqrt[2*Pi] == 0*)
```

Converting this by hand to an ode MMa can work with:

```
fteq = EI s^4 ys[t] + μ ys''[t] + y[L/2, t] (k E^((I L s)/2))/Sqrt[2 π] == 0

sol = DSolve[fteq, ys[t], t] // Flatten
```

We get a solution, but not knowing `y[L/2,t]` this is about as far as we can go. MMa can invert the FourierTransform for a constant value for `y[L/2,t]` and presumably for other functions of `t`, but with the DiracDelta function at `x = L/2`, it is hard to know the value of y there.

Comment: Hmm… I'm afraid this answer isn't correct, because `FourierTransform` is a tool for solving differential equation defined in a unbounded domain, while OP's problem is bounded in $[0,L]$. It might be possible to first extend the domain periodically and then solve the problem with `FourierTransform`, I myself never succeeded though…

Answer (score 0):

After

```
eqn = EI D[y[x, t], {x, 4}] + μ D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] + k DiracDelta[x - L/2] y[x, t] == 0;
ic = {y[x, 0] == Sin[x/L Pi], Derivative[0, 1][y][x, 0] == 0};
bc = {y[0, t] == 0, y[L, t] == 0, Derivative[2, 0][y][0, t] == 0, Derivative[2, 0][y][L, t] == 0};
teqn = With[{l = LaplaceTransform}, l[{eqn, bc}, t, s] /. HoldPattern@l[u_, t, s] :> u] /. Rule @@@ ic
```

we need to do

```
teqns = teqn /. {t-> s}
```

and then

```
DSolve[teqns, y, {x, s}]
```

To have a result, suppose that instead we have (without the DiracDelta)

```
teqns = \[Mu] (-s Sin[(\[Pi] x)/L] + s^2 y[x, s]) + EI D[y[x,s],{x,4}] == 0
```

so following with

```
yxs = y[x,s] /. DSolve[teqns, y, {x, s}]
```

we obtain an output that should be concluded by

```
yxt = InverseLaplaceTransform[yxs, s, t]
```

There are many issues to handle. It seems that **DSolve** doesn't like the DiracDelta in the PDE and also the boundary conditions are not so easy to handle.

Comment: `DSolve[teqns, y, {x, s}]` returns the input in version 12.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: It gives to me with the same version $$\left\{c_1(s) e^{\frac{(-1)^{3/4} \sqrt[4]{\mu } \sqrt{s} x}{\sqrt[4]{\text{EI}}}}+c_2(s) e^{-\frac{\sqrt[4]{-1} \sqrt[4]{\mu } \sqrt{s}
   x}{\sqrt[4]{\text{EI}}}}+c_3(s) e^{-\frac{(-1)^{3/4} \sqrt[4]{\mu } \sqrt{s} x}{\sqrt[4]{\text{EI}}}}+c_4(s) e^{\frac{\sqrt[4]{-1} \sqrt[4]{\mu }
   \sqrt{s} x}{\sqrt[4]{\text{EI}}}}+\frac{\mu  L^4 s \sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{L}\right)}{\left(\pi ^2 \sqrt{\text{EI}}-i \sqrt{\mu } L^2 s\right) \left(\pi
   ^2 \sqrt{\text{EI}}+i \sqrt{\mu } L^2 s\right)}\right\}$$

Comment: Now if $c_1(s)=c_2(s)=c_3(s)=c_4(s)=0$ due to boundary conditions we will get $$y(x,t)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{L}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi ^2 \sqrt{\text{EI}} t}{\sqrt{\mu } L^2}\right)$$