# Solution of Fokker-Planck equation with delta initiall condition - everywhere zero

Tags: differential-equations

I try to solve a Fokker-Planck equation (which I derived from corresponding Ito equation)

$\partial_tp=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 \partial_{x_i}(\mu_i p)+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^4
\sum\limits_{j=1}^4\partial^2_{x_i,x_j}[D_{ij}p],
D_{ij}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^2\sigma_{ik}\sigma_{jk}$,

my code is:

```
appro = With[{k = 1}, Erf[k #]/2 + 1/2 &]

sigma := 1/
   Sqrt[2]*{{Sqrt[gamma/n]*(n + 1)*2*
     a, (Sqrt[gamma/n]*(n + 1)*2*b)}, {-Sqrt[gamma*n]*2*
     a, -(Sqrt[gamma*n]*2*b)},
   {-Sqrt[gamma*n]*p00 + Sqrt[gamma/n]*(n + 1)*p11, 
    I (-Sqrt[gamma*n]*p00 + Sqrt[gamma/n]*(n + 1)*p11)},
   {-Sqrt[gamma*n]*p00 + 
     Sqrt[gamma/n]*(n + 1)*
      p11, -I (-Sqrt[gamma*n]*p00 + Sqrt[gamma/n]*(n + 1)*p11)}};

Dd = Table[0, {i, 4}, {j, 4}];

Do[Dd[[i, j]] = Sum[sigma[[i, k]]*sigma[[j, k]], {k, 1, 2}], {i, 1, 
  4}, {j, 1, 4}]

mu = {-gamma*n*p00 + gamma*(n + 1)*p11, 
  gamma*n*p00 - gamma*(n + 1)*p11, (2*dn + d)*b - 
   gamma*(2*n + 1)*a, -(2*dn + d)*a - gamma*(2*n + 1) b}

gamma = 1;
d = 1;
dn = 1;
n = 1

psol = First[p /. NDSolve[{D[p[p00, p11, a, b, t], t] + 
       D[mu[[1]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p00] + 
       D[mu[[2]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p11] + 
       D[mu[[3]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], a] + 
       D[mu[[4]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], b] - 
       0.5*(D[D[Dd[[1, 1]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p00] + 
            D[Dd[[2, 1]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p11] + 
            D[Dd[[3, 1]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], a] + 
            D[Dd[[4, 1]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], b], p00] + 
          D[D[Dd[[1, 2]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p00] + 
             D[Dd[[2, 2]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p11] + 
             D[Dd[[3, 2]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], a] + 
             D[Dd[[4, 2]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], b], p11] +D[
            D[Dd[[1, 3]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p00] + 
             D[Dd[[2, 3]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p11] + 
             D[Dd[[3, 3]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], a] + 
             D[Dd[[4, 3]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], b], a]+ D[
            D[Dd[[1, 4]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p00] + 
             D[Dd[[2, 4]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], p11] + 
             D[Dd[[3, 4]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], a] + 
             D[Dd[[4, 4]]*p[p00, p11, a, b, t], b], b]) == 0, 
     p[p00, p11, a, b, 0] == 
      appro'[p00 - 0.3]*appro'[p11 - 0.7]*appro'[a - 0.2]*
       appro'[b - 0.1], 
     p[10, p11, a, b, t] == p[-10, p11, a, b, t] == 
      p[p00, 10, a, b, t] == p[p00, -10, a, b, t] == 
      p[p00, p11, 10, b, t] == p[p00, p11, -10, b, t] == 
      p[p00, p11, a, 10, t] == p[p00, p11, a, -10, t] == 0}, 
    p, {t, 0, 10}, {p00, -10, 10}, {p11, -10, 10}, {a, -10, 
     10}, {b, -10, 10}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
```

"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 25,
      "MinPoints" -> 25, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}]]

My Mathemtica quits the kernel, when I start the calculation.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Your code returns an error. The best thing you can do in this situation is to write a simpler version of your equation just to see that your syntax is right (a minimal working example). It is currently not. For example, your `Dd` variable definition does not work. I think a better way to achieve what you want is to write `Dd = sigma.Transpose[sigma]`

Comment: I think now it is ok.

Comment: I don't think a numeric solver like `NDSolve` will be able cope with a `DiracDelta`, it will just see it as something that is zero everywhere. The `DiracDelta` is for symbolic calculations.

Comment: I have approximated DiracDelta ( by function appro - see above), I still get zero everywhere...

Comment: 1. The position of `MaxSteps` is wrong. 2. The `bcart` warning is a more serious problem, check [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871) for more information. You need to add proper boundary condition. 3. The approximate `DiracDelta` is probably too slender, try a smaller `k`, a denser spatial grid may be also necessary. (I think you've already read [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131112/1871)?)

Comment: I have changed the positon of MaxStep, chosen smaller k, included boundary conditions and chosen MaxStepSize->0.1. My Mathematica quits the kernel all the time when I start the calculation...

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get a reminder. I suspect the RAM of your PC is eaten up. `k = 5` still results in a quite sharp approximation of `DiracDelta`, to accurately represent it, a dense spatial grid is needed. (Just try `With[{n = 25}, 
 Plot[appro'[t], {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]~Show~
  Plot[Interpolation[Table[{t, appro'[t]}, {t, -10, 10, 20/(n - 1)}], 
      InterpolationOrder -> 4][t] // Evaluate, {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]]`, you can adjust the `n` and observe. ) For a 5 dimentional problem, `k = 5` may be too expensive.

Comment: Also, notice `MaxSteps` and `MaxStepSize` is for adjustion of time step (the `t` in your case), while for your problem, the crucial part is the adjustion of spatial grid size. (`p00`, `p11`, `a`, `b`. )

Comment: ……And, your translation for $\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^4
\sum\limits_{j=1}^4\partial^2_{x_i,x_j}[D_{ij}p]$ is wrong. You missed 2 `+`. A simple and clear way to deduce it with _Mathematica_ is: `var = {p00, p11, a, b};
sum2 = 1/2 Total@
    Flatten@Table[
      D[p[p00, p11, a, b, t] Dd[[i, j]], var[[i]], var[[j]]], {i, 4}, {j, 4}];`

Comment: @xzczd , I have set k=1, added missing 2 +, set MaxSteps -> 10^3,MaxStepSize -> {1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01}, Mathematica still quits the kernel, also when I set smaller interval for calculating, p00,...,b

Comment: By setting MaxStepSize -> {1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1} it seems that the calculation doesn't abort... I still wait for the output.

Comment: Well, as mentioned above, `MaxStepSize` is an option for the adjustion of **time** step. To adjust the spatial grid size, use e.g. `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 25, "MinPoints" -> 25, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}` (This defines a 2nd order spatial grid, with 25 points for each dimension. BTW suppose `NDSolve` uses `10^4` steps for time integration, you'll need `25^4 8/1024^3. 10^4 "GB"` memory to finish the calculation.) BTW, I've define a `mol` function for this task in the link above.

Comment: @xzczd , Although I have enough space on my computer (over 50GB), the computation is always aborted after some time and Mathematica quits the kernel.

Comment: I think it would be good to first make sure the equation itself is correct. Can you talk a bit more about the definition of `sigma` and `mu`?